# jquery returns the text of selected item in select tag plus text of selected item in other select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, select

I have two `select` tags in my website. When I try to get the text of selected item in one `select` tag, I see that it returns the two texts of the two `select` tags, even if I specify which select to retrive data from via  a class attribute.

My code is

```
$('select.select').change(function(e) {

e.preventDefault(); 
var val1 = $(' option:selected').text();
alert(val1);


});

$('select.select2').change(function(e) {

e.preventDefault(); 

var val2 = $(' option:selected').text();
alert(val2);


});
```

The alerts are always containing the text of the two `select` tags concatenated.

Your usual help is appreciated.

Comment: the variables names you have chosen make me wonder if what you truly desire is the value of the select instead of the text of the selected option.  Sometimes they are the same but the former makes for more portable code.  e.g. within your change callback it would be: `$(this).val()`

Comment: I am totally agreeing with you, when I changed it to var val1 = $('option:selected', this).text(); it is working now based on Simon Adcock answer, it is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps update the selector to specify the context of the selection:

```
$('select.select').change(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault(); 
  var val1 = $('option:selected', this).text();
  alert(val1);

  return false;

  });
```

The selector `$('option:selected', this)` will return values found within the context of the changed element.

Comment: Thank you for your quick feedback. I will test it and come back to give a feedback.

Comment: perfect. Thanks so much, I hope I can be one day of such efficient and quick help to the community.

Comment: Thanks very much! Judging from your answers so far, you already are a great help to the community :)

Answer (score 1):

It is because of this `$('option:selected').text();` you have two selected option in your page so it returns two values.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this:

```
// Call the change event for the select
$('select.select').change(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    // Get the selected option for the select in current scope
    var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    alert(text );

    //return false;   No need of this, as we already called the preventDefault() method
});
```

Comment: yes I am totally agreeing with you, when I added 'this' based on Simon Adcock answer it is working. I will remove the return false as you advised, thank you for your time.

Comment: Also, a suggestion, you can use the same class `select` for both the select dropdowns and the above code will work for both. No need to write two change events with the same logic.

Comment: I agree with you but in my case i need more work since I have put different CSS based on the difference of class. thanks a lot

Comment: Ok, cool. That's was just a suggestion to make your better, faster and lesser :)

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify the class when you retrieve the value:

```
var val1 = $('.select option:selected').text();
```

and

```
var val2 = $('.select2 option:selected').text();
```

Comment: I see what you mean but I already did this I just forgot to mention it in my post, i will edit